# how can i implement voice based search that extracts data from api and shows the result using angular and ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am making an app but I am stuck.I want to implement voice based search that search results from API using angular and ionic . I have searched it everywhere on internet but could not find a solution

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using this plugin?
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/speech-recognition

After recognition and receive text you can use your default api for search by text (I hope that it exists)